# How to extract <h2> tag information from html file while indexing them in Solr

Tags: solr

I want to extract the `<h2>` tag information from html file while indexing them in Solr.

For example: In test.htm file i have content like `<h2>This is for test</h2>`

I need to extract `This is for test` in h2 index.

I found under conf/managed-schema file already have 'h1' field defined which extract the information from `<h1>` tag from html which is working fine.

Defined as: `<field name="h1" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

So, i want to do same for `<h2>` tag which is not working.

I tried : `<field name="h2" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

I am indexing the test.htm file by running command: `/var/www/html/solr-5.3.1/bin/post -p 9000 -c Core -filetypes htm,html /var/www/html/test/Core/test.htm`

I am stuck with this...can anybody please help me out?

Comment: How are you indexing these pages?

Comment: /var/www/html/solr-5.3.1/bin/post -p 9000 -c Core -filetypes htm,html /var/www/html/test/Core/test.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after done lots of R&D I get the solution :-).

I added `<str name="capture">h2</str>
        <str name="fmap.h2">h2</str>` into the solrconfig.xml and it start working.

So, my final solrconfig.xml looks like:

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
              startup="lazy"
              class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="lowernames">true</str>
        <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
        <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
        <str name="capture">h1</str>
        <str name="fmap.h1">h1</str>
        <str name="capture">h2</str>
        <str name="fmap.h2">h2</str>        
        <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

That's it :-)

Might be some other user can face same problem in future so, i am posting this as answer.